# Set data attribute after ajax success

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have an input like this:

```
<input class="txthoras" type="text" value="" data-fetxa="2013/02/24" data-lineaid="">
```

On my CoffeScript file I write a function like this:

```
$('.txthoras').blur ->
   that=this
   url = Routing.generate('post_lineas')
        $.ajax url,
            type: "POST"
            data: { proyectoid: proyectoid, hitoid: hitoid, tareaid: tareaid, usuarioid: usuarioid, fetxa: fetxa, totalhoras:that.value }
            contentType: "application/json"
            success: (data) ->
              $(tr).effect "highlight" , {}, 1500
              $(that).effect "pulsate", { times:3 }, 1000
              datos = undefined
              if data is "null"
                $("#divmaterialincorrecto").show "slow"
              else
                datos = jQuery.parseJSON(data)
                $(that).data "lineaid", datos.id

            error: (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) ->
              $(tr).effect "highlight", { color:"#CC3232"}, 1500
              $(that).effect "shake", { times:3 }, 300
              console.log "Errorea"
              alert xhr.status
              alert thrownError
```

The ajax works fine and it returns the data, I checked that.

Now, if I set `$(that).data "lineaid", datos.id` and check if it is written to the dom, it doesn't. But if I write console.log `$(that).data "lineaid"` it displays the data.

The fact is that I have another function (PUT) where I need this data, and it is empty when it is launched.

Any help or clue?

All the code in CoffeScript: http://pastebin.com/WcQcNnPz
All the code in JavaScript: http://pastebin.com/RtZ02Wh4

thanks in advance

Comment: Attributes that you *set* with `$(foo).data('foo', 17)` will not be written to the DOM -- that is, it won't create a `data-foo` attribute. They are only *read* but never *written*, with the `data()` method. See jQuery's [data() docs](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5): *The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).*

Comment: ammmhhhhh oks! Can you write that like an answer to close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a big difference between HTML5 `data-` attributes and jQuery's [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5) method. While jQuery will *read* all the `data-` attributes (once, the first time you run `$(foo).data()`), it will never write them to the DOM. From the docs:

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values are then stored internally in jQuery).

So your findings are entirely expected. If you don't actually *need* the attribute to be in the HTML source, you don't have to do anything. If you do for some reason, you will have to use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method instead.